# Show all JNDI names in Wildlfy 9

Tags: jndi, wildfly

What is the correct way to show registered JNDI names in Wildfly 9?

For older versions it was possible to use `/subsystem=naming:jndi-view`, however it seems not working anymore. When running in domain mode.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What doesn't work anymore? Any error reported?

Comment: I am getting: `/subsystem=naming:jndi-view
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [(\"subsystem\" => \"naming\")]",
    "rolled-back" => true
}`

Comment: Do you have naming subsystem preset in standalone.xml you are running? In default config it is present.

Comment: Yes, I do. In `domain.xml`: in **extensions** : `<extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>` and further (in **full-ha** profile): `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
                <remote-naming/>
            </subsystem>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you are running in domain mode you need to tell server in which profile you are interested in jndi names.

running `/subsystem=naming:jndi-view` executes command on domain controller itself not on some profile that actually has subsystems defined.

to get what you want you would need to execute jndi-view operation on actual server running inside your domain.

For example :

```
/host=master/server=server-one/subsystem=naming:jndi-view
```

would return you jndi-view of server `server-one` on host `master`

Answer (score 7):

The graphical way also worked for me, navigating to admin console and going for:

`Runtime` -> `Standalone server` -> `Subsystems` -> `JNDI View` -> `View`

Comment: My wildfly 10 server is starting without error but when I navigate to admin console it throws the following error ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 9) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("jndi-view") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "naming")])